# Element Disappears In Dev Tools

Tags: css, styles, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

**Scenario**

I click on an element in the CSS `styles` tab of Chrome dev tools and then click the `+` symbol to add an instance of the selected element so I can make independent changes to it, this action creates an instance of the selected element (image 1).

**Problem**

When I click in-between the curly braces of the new instance of the element in the styles tab it then disappears (image 2).

Does anyone know why this his happening and how to prevent it? This doesn't happen when I follow the same procedure in FireFox and I've not encountered it before. It is also happening on every element.

[image]

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Can't reproduce it

Comment: @j08691 I don't understand your comment?  The site is on a localhost set up so I don't have a link if that's what you mean?

Comment: @TheChewy There's something specific to your setup that is causing the issue as I also cannot reproduce this. I suspect it could be an issue with the SASS source map. Try disabling it in Settings by unchecking "Enable CSS source maps" and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: @GideonPyzer  Hi Gideon, I did this but it had no effect. :(  I might see if I can upload the site (it's just a static site) so people can take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem stopped happening when I updated my version of SASS.